# Can I transform this sentence like this?

Tags: sentence-patterns

This is the original sentence:
"The guests reached the wedding party last night though it rained heavily."
I transformed it to:
"It rained heavily last night;however, the guests reached the wedding party."
Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you want to transform the sentence? In my opinion the first version is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

I like to put context prior to subject matter when able. As such, my extrapolation of the sentence would be as follows: 'Despite heavy rainfall last night, the guests arrived safely for the wedding party.'

Comment: Upvoted because you included rationale. Seems to me that placement depends on which bit of information you want to emphasize, but in any case there should be some consideration as to *why* a given ordering of sentence elements is chosen.

Comment: Actually, I want to ask if it is safe to put "last night" after "it rained heavily".

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is preferable, but if you would rather it be transformed you might say:

Though it rained heavily last night, the guests reached the wedding party.

Leave out the ";however,". Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, I want to ask if it is safe to put "last night" after "it rained heavily".

Comment: Yes, it describes when it rained in addition to how it rained all in one clause.

Comment: Despite its position in the first sentence?

Comment: I see your point.  You could also say - Though it rained heavily, the guests reached the wedding party last night.  It only depends on what you want to emphasize with phrase "last night" (raining or arriving).